# How did the information from the black hole do this?

Tags: plot-explanation, interstellar

I've just seen *Interstellar* and I have two questions:

- How did the information from the black hole save humanity?
- What was that information about? I would rather not hear that "it's about the answer" I'd like to hear THE answer.

Comment: The other question is definitely related - but it approaches it from the point of view of 'what do they do with the equation' rather than 'what was the information they were seeking'.

Comment: If we knew the answer we'd be living in space ;P

Answer (score 14):

### The information was about gravity, intended to allow NASA to develop technology to manipulate gravity.

Gravitational anomalies such as the wormhole were detected by NASA.  This told them that the manipulation of gravity was possible.  "Plan A" was ostensibly to work towards exploiting this technology to cheaply escape the bounds of the Earth and expand into space, grow food in space-stations etc.

This is explained to Cooper by Professor Brand when touring the NASA site:

> **Cooper**: This entire facility's a centrifuge. Some kind of vehicle. A space station?
>
> **Brand**: Both. Plan A.
>
> **Cooper**: How do you get it off the ground?
>
> **Brand**: The first gravitational anomalies changed everything. Suddenly we knew that harnessing gravity was real.

However by the time that this conversation is taking place, Professor Brand has already 'hit a wall' in discovering how this gravity manipulation works.  However he pretends that he is continuing to work on Plan-A, while persuading Cooper to take the Endurance and the Plan-B population bomb to the other solar system.

Amelia Brand and Cooper theorize that the data they could collect from within the black hole might allow Earth to crack the gravity problem.  It's a long shot but they send TARS into the black hole to collect this data.

The 'bulk beings' (our descendants in the far future) send Cooper into the Tesseract, the 'bookshelf' space designed by them to allow Cooper to communicate with Murph and transmit the data.